# Neo4J Cypher query - IN collection?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a simple graph database which contains two types.

BlogPost
Tag

A BlogPost can have many tags.

I've written a BlogPost and given it 4 tags. I'd like to search for other BlogPosts which contain at least these four tags.

I've tried

```
MATCH (b:BlogPost{id='156'})-[:tagged]->(original_tag)
WITH b, collect(original_tag) AS original_tags
MATCH (b2)-[:tagged]-(second_blog_tag)
WITH b, original_tags, collect(second_blog_tag) AS second_blog_tags, b2
WHERE original_tags IN second_blog_tags
RETURN b2.id
```

However the line

```
WHERE original_tags IN second_blog_tags
```

is wrong. Can anyone offer any assistance? Is my thinking about using collects correct or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH (b:BlogPost{id='156'})-[:tagged]->(original_tag)
WITH b, collect(original_tag) AS original_tags
MATCH (b2)-[:tagged]-(second_blog_tag)
WITH b, original_tags, collect(second_blog_tag) AS second_blog_tags, b2
WHERE ALL(tag IN original_tags WHERE tag IN second_blog_tags)
RETURN b2.id
```

you can also try:

```
MATCH (b:BlogPost{id='156'})-[:tagged]->(original_tag)<-[:tagged]-(b2:BlogPost)
WITH b, b2, count(distinct original_tag) as tagCount
WHERE tagCount = size((b)-[:tagged]->())
RETURN b2.id
```

Comment: Correct and very helpful - thanks very much. I'm new to cypher and struggling to understand how to compare sets from two queries - this answer has really helped me